# I want to draw rect in d3 along x axis with no overlapping of rect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, d3.js

I want to draw rect along x axis with given set of array of data and if two rect are overlapping, move one to other positions.

I'm using d3 force simulation but if there is overlapping, d3 move data along y axis.

Here are my three datasets

```js
let data1 = [2,2,4,5,6,6,2,8]

let data2 = [2,3,4,5,6,8,8,8]

let data3 = [2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,8,9,10]
```

I used `scaleLinear` to scale data with respect to width and I fixed the y of rect but in force simulation it is not working.

Comment: What have you tried so far? (show the code, not just the data sets)